# active nabber using js , how can I set the mobile version

Tags: javascript, css

I have a active navbar "dynamic navbar using js " which is run perfectly on desktop version and tablet version and any mobile greater than 320 in width

how can I set it in less than 320?
the solution in css or js?
and how?

this is a css code with a Medea q 
I removed some code you don't need it :)

I need to understand the solution

````
const callback = entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        const navListElement = document.querySelector(
            `.menu__link[data-link='${entry.target.id}']`,
        )
        const section = document.getElementById(entry.target.id)

        if (entry && entry.isIntersecting) {
            navListElement.classList.add('active')
            section.classList.add('active')
        } else {
            if (navListElement.classList.contains('active')) {
                navListElement.classList.remove('active')
            }

            if (section.classList.contains('active')) {
                section.classList.remove('active')
            }
        }
    })
}```


css












/* ---- Layout Rules ---- */




/* ---- Module Rules ---- */

/* Navigation Styles*/
.navbar__menu ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: right;
}

.navbar__menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.navbar__menu li,
.navbar__menu .menu__link {
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: ease 0.3s all;
}

.navbar__menu li:hover,
.navbar__menu .menu__link:hover {
    background: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar__menu li:hover a,
.navbar__menu .menu__link:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar__menu .menu__link.active {
    background-color: #333;
}









.landing__container {
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: left;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 35em) {
    .main-hero {
        margin: auto;
    }
    .landing__container {
        max-width: 50em;
        padding: 4em;
    }
    .navbar__menu li,
    .navbar__menu .menu__link {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}










section.active .landing__container::before {
    opacity: 1;
    animation: rotate 4s linear 0s infinite forwards;
}

section.active .landing__container::after {
    opacity: 1;
    animation: rotate 5s linear 0s infinite forwards reverse;
}




}
````

Answer (score 0):

Well, you might want to show us the CSS classes you have and media-queries.

@Also, you can use .toggle(className, true/false) instead of repeating yourself with adding, removing a class.

@edit1:

So you have this snippet:

```
if (navListElement.classList.contains('active')) {
      navListElement.classList.remove('active')
}
```

This becomes:

```
navListElement.classList.toggle('active, false)
```

```
navListElement.classList.add('active')
```

---

This becomes:

```
navListElement.classList.toggle('active', true);
```

For under 320px Mobile, you can use CSS media query as well:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 35em)
```

Comment: I do , how can I used ? more details pls

Comment: same problem , it is work as navigate but it not show the user which section "above 320px it show btw"